# Is it possible to distinguish between needing a regular cable and crossover cable from the CLI?

Tags: command-line, ethernet, lan

The value of `/sys/class/net/ethX/carrier` can be used to determine if the computer is connected or not.

Is it possible to make the destinction between being connected to a hub/switch are another computer (which would require ever a crossover cable, or a network interface which supports "crossing" itself)?

**Update**:

After reading the answers (thanks!) it seems, providing a more specific use case might (hopefully) help to clarify the intention of the question:

The idea is to have a device which supports two operating "modes":

- regular - e.g. when attached to a switch
- config - e.g. when directly attached to a computer using a regular cable (NOT crossover), which would usually require a crossover cable to work

In config mode the device could start a DHCP server and allow configuration of parameters not  allowed in "regular" mode.

So the question would be, can the device itself detect it is connected to a computer and by that switch from regular to config mode?
(with the assumption the user is using a regular cable since they might not even know, that such things as crossover cables exist...)

Answer (score 1):

Ethernet doesn't have any form of client/server if that's what you mean.  There's no practical difference between wiring into a switch vs wiring into another computer.

The crossover cable is only required because switches have their pins wired back-to-front so that they listen on the wire the computer talks on, and talk on the wire the computer listens to...  Wiring computer-to-computer needs the cable to swap them over.

There's one very subtle difference with a hub which may be noticeable.  Since hubs don't interpret the packets in any way, the forward every packet to every other device, it may be possible to detect that packets are being sent to a computer which are (mac) addressed for another machine.

Answer (score 0):

It would not be possible to directly determine if a crossover cable is in use via software means, because there is no difference as far as the hardware is concerned (assuming it works at all).  A host to switch connection doesn't need a cross over.  A switch to switch or host to host connection would need a cross over -- but as per current ethernet standards, either end could automatically activate a cross over on its port.  So unless you know that a) it is one of these combinations, and b) neither side activated automatic cross over, there would be no way to know.

It might be possible to determine if a port has detected that it needs to internally cross over because a cross over was needed but not used.

It might be possible to guess if a cross over was used by looking at the device types (host vs. switch) on both sides of the cable and making sure that neither one activated its own port's cross over, but typically this information isn't available anyway, so it still might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

`ethtool` shows a line about the MDI/X -mode of the NIC, it says unknown on the system I tested, but I presume it works on *some* systems.

Not that that helps you: if you see a locally crossed-over link, you still can't tell if it's because there's a straight cable to another host, or a crossed-over cable to a switch. And if you see no local cross-over, you still can't know if the remote switched to cross-mode.

But, I also wonder what the use of detecting the cable would be? With practically all devices supporting auto-MDI/X, the exact details of the cable are a rather insignificant low-level detail, a bit like the length of the cable.

Knowing if you're connected to a switch or a computer (over the immediate physical link) also doesn't tell much, since a computer can act as a bridge almost like a dedicated switch, and a switch can be connected to with SSH like a computer.

If you're trying to figure out if you should DHCP or something like Zeroconf, you can't make that decision based on the physical link either, for similar reasons. If you're connected to a switch, there might or might not be a DHCP server also connected. If you're connected to a computer, the other end might or might not be running one. So it has to be decided on a higher level than the immediate link.

Answer (score 0):

`ethtool` can show you the state of MDI-X

```
...
Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        MDI-X: on (auto)
...
```

However as others pointed out, this is only the state of your local machine, you can't know about the used cable or the MDI-X state of the other machine.

`ethtool` allows you to force MDIX on or off instead of the default auto-MDIX.

`ethtool -s devname [mdix auto|on|off]`

You could then observe if a connection can be established or not. If a connection is successful regardless of the state, the other machine supports auto-MDI-X.

Note that **all**  gigabit ethernet devices support auto-MDI-X.

For testing if a cable is straight-thru or crossover, you can use a cheap RJ45 cabletester.

Comment: `For testing if a cable is straight-thru or crossover, you can use a cheap RJ45 cabletester.` ... or just eyeball the wiring.  Its obvious enough that crossover cables have different colour on one end to the other where a straight patch lead is identical both ends :-)